No such table: cafe | startup page not loading after user names cafe
The database creates as I see the file "data.sqlite" but the startup page isn't loading after the user enters the name of the cafe. In fact, it redirects the user to /nameCafe after naming their cafe in /newgame but I want them to be redirected to /startup after they name their cafe in /newgame.
This is what the console says:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: cafe
[SQL: INSERT INTO cafe ("cafeName", "loanID", "investorID", "dishID", "loadGameID", "discountID", "totalFC", date, level) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('cafe', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)]
Here's my current code:
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(
    "app",
    template_folder="templates",  # name of folder containing html templates
    static_folder="static"  # name of folder for static files
)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ('sqlite:///' +
                                     os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite'))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)


class Cafe(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'cafe'

  def __init__(self, name=None):
    self.cafeName = name

  cafeID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  cafeName = db.Column(db.String(100))
  loanID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('loans.loanID'))
  investorID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('investors.investorID'))
  dishID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dishes.dishID'))
  loadGameID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('loadgame.loadGameID'))
  discountID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('discounts.discountID'))
  totalFC = db.Column(db.Float)
  date = db.Column(db.Date)
  level = db.Column(db.Integer)


class Loan(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'loans'

  def __init__(self, loan=20000.00):
    self.amount = loan

  loanID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  amount = db.Column(db.Float)
  interestRate = db.Column(db.Float)
  amountLeftToPay = db.Column(db.Float)
  cafeID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cafe.cafeID'))


class Investor(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'investors'

  investorID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  amountInvested = db.Column(db.Float)
  equity = db.Column(db.Integer)
  cafeID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cafe.cafeID'))


class LoadGame(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'loadgame'

  loadGameID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  lgSlot1 = db.Column(db.String(100), default="Empty Slot")
  lgSlot2 = db.Column(db.String(100), default="Empty Slot")
  lgSlot3 = db.Column(db.String(100), default="Empty Slot")


class Calendar(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'calendar'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  dayOfWeek = db.Column(db.String)
  timeOfDay = db.Column(db.String)
  monthName = db.Column(db.String)


class Discounts(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'discounts'

  discountID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  discountTimeFrame = db.Column(db.String(100))
  discountedPrice = db.Column(db.Float)


class Dishes(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'dishes'

  dishID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  requiredLevel = db.Column(db.Integer)
  dishPrice = db.Column(db.Float)


class fixedCosts(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'fixedcosts'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  totalFixedCosts = db.Column(db.Integer)
  taxes = db.Column(db.Float)
  currentMonth = db.Column(db.Date)
  rent = db.Column(db.Float)


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/newgame')
def newgame():
  return render_template('newgame.html')


@app.route('/nameCafe', methods=['POST','GET'])
def name_cafe():    
  if request.method == 'POST':
    cafe_name = request.form['cafe_name']
    if cafe_name and len(cafe_name) <= 20: 
        new_cafe = Cafe(cafe_name)
        db.session.add(new_cafe)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('startup', cafe_id=new_cafe.cafeID))
    else:
      print("here")
      new_cafe = Cafe()
      print("here")
      return redirect(url_for('startup'))
  else:
    return render_template('newgame.html')

@app.route('/startup')
def startup(cafe_id):
    cafe = Cafe.query.get_or_404(cafe_id)
    print(f"Starting cafe: {cafe.cafeName}")
    return render_template('startup.html', cafe=cafe)

# @app.route('/startup/<int:cafe_id>')
# def startup(cafe_id):
#     cafe = Cafe.query.get_or_404(cafe_id)
#     return render_template('startup.html', cafe=cafe)


@app.route('/loadgame')
def loadgame():
  return render_template('loadgame.html')


@app.route('/settings')
def settings():
  return render_template('settings.html')

@app.route('/startup')
def startupw():
  return render_template('startup.html')
# now it works but must manually enter startup; also it doesnt work with the newgame page

if __name__ == '__main__':
  db.create_all()
  app.run(debug=True)
  #app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)


Move the migrate to after all your models have all been defined.

@snakecharmerb hey, thanks for answering. I did so but nothings seemed to change. However, could you run me through on what moving migrate after defining my models does?

Flask-SQLALchemy registers models with db (technically with its metadata attribute) as they are read. If you migrate (or do db.create_all) before the model definitions are read by the interpreter, then unread definitions are not migrated or created.   This also applies to imported definitions: all model definitions must be imported into the same namespace as db before migration or creation takes place.

Okay thanks @snakecharmerb, is it the reason why it says "no such table as cafe" ?

I do still need help for anyone who views this and appreciate all the help possible.
